# Background image from JSON

Tags: php, html, json

Alright, so I have a json file stored like the following,

```
{  
   "market_name":"\u2605 Bayonet",
   "market_hash_name":"\u2605 Bayonet",
   "icon_url":"\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQh5hlcX0nvUOGsx8DdQBJjIAVHubSaKQZ53P3NZXMXvYmykdLSxqWkZ7-HkjMIvpIj3u2Y84733gzh_RU_MG_zIYLEdQ45fxiOrdJh0ExF",
   "name_color":"8650AC",
   "quality_color":"EB4B4B"
}
```

Now using PHP I'm getting `icon_url` and then I'm trying to add this as a background image, but since the url has all these `/\/\` it won't work for a background image. How can I solve this?

This is how I'm trying to echo the div,

```
    <div class='image' style='background-image:url('" . $icon . "')'></div>
```

Edit: it does work when used with `<img>` but I'm soly looking for `background-image`

This is the full code used:

```
$getInventory = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `inventories` WHERE `user` = '.$db->quote($user['steamid']));
        $fetchInventory = $getInventory->fetchAll();

        $prices = file_get_contents('pricesdb.txt');$prices = json_decode($prices, true);
        $images = file_get_contents('iconsdb.txt');$images = json_decode($images, true);

        $inventoryArray = array();
        foreach ($fetchInventory as $key => $value) {
            $item = $value['item'];
            $id = $value['id'];
            $worth = number_format($prices['response']['items'][$item]['value']/100, 2, '.', 1);
            $icon;
            $rarity;

            foreach($images['items'] as $key => $value){            
                if($value['market_hash_name'] == $item){                    
                    $icon = $value['icon_url'];
                    $rarity = $value['quality_color'];
                }           
            }           

            $item_wear = preg_replace('/^.*(\(.*\)).*$/', '$1', $item);
            $item_wear_short = preg_replace("/(?![A-Z])./", "", $item_wear);
            $item_rarity = $rarity;

            $exp_item_version = explode(" | ", str_replace($item_wear,"", $item));

            $item_version = $exp_item_version[0];
            $item_name = $exp_item_version[1];

            $itemArray = array($id, $icon, $worth, $item_version, $item_rarity, $item_name);

            array_push($inventoryArray, $itemArray);
        }       

        usort($inventoryArray, function($a, $b) {
            return $b[2] - $a[2];
        });

        foreach ($inventoryArray as $key => $value) {
            $id = $inventoryArray[$key][0];
            $icon = $inventoryArray[$key][1];
            $worth = $inventoryArray[$key][2];
            $item_version = $inventoryArray[$key][3];
            $item_rarity = $inventoryArray[$key][4];
            $item_name = $inventoryArray[$key][5];

            echo "<div class='item'  data-item='" . $id . "'>
            <div class='rarity rarity-gold'></div>
            <div class='image' style='background-image:url('" . $icon . "')'></div>
            <div class='market-name'>
            <div class='type'>
            " . convert_ascii($item_version) . "
            </div>
            <div class='name'>
            " . $item_name . "
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class='wear'>
            FN
            </div>
            <div class='price'>$" . $worth . "</div>
            </div>
            ";

        }
```

Comment: How are you getting this url? json_decode should remove these.

Comment: '\/' is the common way to escape a slash. Is it saving the escape so that $icon pulls it? If that's so, why is it there? Can't it be handled somewhere else rather than in the data?

Comment: @Jerodev I updated it, and uploaded all code used, but I did use decode.

Comment: Change `background-image` to `background`.

Comment: @insidesin whenever I inspect element it shows me the image's url with all spaces for the `/`

Comment: @Oen44 doesn't work sadly.

Comment: If you inspect `div` element and check `background-image` value, can you open that url? Does it open image?

Comment: @Oen44 no it does not,
this is the url that is within the html
`steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net="" economy="" image="" -9a81dlwlwj2uugcvs_nsvtzdoedtwwkgzzlqhtxdz7i56ku0zwwo4nux4ofjzehlbxh5apeo4ymlhxyqkncrvco04devlxkkgpovbsslqjf2placdba5cijly20kpb5prrukmrb-ml0mnbr_y3mjqelpxo7oy3td9ldiqztyvce_fs8x-fqjz_vv5mbnhzq7nn25yrdzr221blfbew7jevefwu1r0v1rw`

Comment: This is the same url but then in the json format `\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpotLu8JAllx8zJfAJF7dG7lb-PmOfkP77DqXtZ6dZ02dbN_Iv9nBrmrkFqYD_xcI_GcQ5rYg6DrAO6xL_mgJ_uvZ2YnXtq6CJ34nqPmkS2n1gSOSUsT3Uj`

Comment: Check my answer. Should help now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here lies your problem.

`style='background-image:url('" . $icon . "')'`

You are using single quotes as `style` and then as `url`. Simple solution.

## Edit

`<div class='image' style='background:url(\"" . $icon . "\")'></div>`

Comment: This is now what I echo `   <div class='image' style='background:url('\"" . $icon . "\"')'></div>
`

It doesn't work, but I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_decode`, `\/\/` will be convert to `//`, it is correct protocol relative path. If it does not work issue is in different place.

Comment: steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net="" economy="" image="" -9a81dlwlwj2uugcvs_nsvtzdoedtwwkgzzlqhtxdz7i56ku0zwwo4nux4of‌​jzehlbxh5apeo4ymlhxy‌​qkncrvco04devlxkkgpo‌​vbsslqjf2placdba5cij‌​ly20kpb5prrukmrb-ml0‌​mnbr_y3mjqelpxo7oy3t‌​d9ldiqztyvce_fs8x-fq‌​jz_vv5mbnhzq7nn25yrd‌​zr221blfbew7jevefwu1‌​r0v1rw –

Answer (score 0):

You can use stripslashes.

```
<?php

$str = '\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_n$

echo (stripslashes($str));
```

For more detailed info please take a look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: does strip slashes but doesn't work for this problem :/ sadly

Comment: May I see the generated HTML code?  <div class='image' style='background-image:url('" . $icon . "')'></div>